# Is "home run" the equivalent of four bases?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, expressions, terminology

> We were all more naive a decade ago. We hoped that a single application of drugs would result in a dramatic benefit. We now understand it's much more complicated than that. People are optimistic but we're not expecting **home runs**. Right now, people would be happy with a series of **singles and doubles**. (Franck Rauscher, the director of the NCI, 1985)

I think a *home run* is going all around the baseball diamond (which consists on reaching the fourth base) and a single is the first base and a double is the second base. Is my understanding correct or is it more than that? Would a *home run* count in points four times reaching a single and twice reaching a double?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A home run is when a single batter gets a hit that allows him to run around all the bases and score a run by crossing home plate.  Crossing home plate is the only way to increase the score.  So a home run is metaphorically something you do once that achieves your goal- i.e., score a run.
Getting singles and doubles is good but it then takes multiple players all getting singles and doubles (and triples) to advance a runner around the bases and eventually score a run.  So in the medical world a single application of drugs that cures the patient might be called a "home run."  But people may be happy with a series of treatments that each do some small part toward an eventual cure- as long as you don't *strike out*.

Comment: Good answer. The two might be mathematically equivalent, but, insofar as a game goes, the situations unfold quite differently. Nice dissection of the metaphor.